# How can I size an element in increments relative to the browser size?

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

I'm trying to make a `DIV` width change as the browser size changes.

Not in some ratio that can be handled with percentage, but still with a dependency for the screen size.
I'm trying to make a div 80% max of the browser width, as long its divided by 20.
if screen is 1000px wide, so the div will be 800px, if the screen is 1024px so it will still be 800px (cause 80% of 1024 is 819.2, not divided by 20).

Except for doing a lot of media queries, I do not know how to do this.

Comment: Are you ok using javascript? Think you'd have to if you don't just do a ton of media queries.

Comment: Also what is the requirement of making it divisible by 20? By having a better idea about what you need to achieve we could offer some better advice.

Comment: You could abuse a preprocessor like SASS to output as much media queries as you need in a loop. If it's for one property of one element, that would be a good try I think

Comment: What if the initial viewport width is 1024px?

Answer (score 0):

This should hopefully get you on your way. It uses jQuery to resize the div by 20px increments. It's not perfect, but it's a start.

http://jsfiddle.net/ydtdS/3/

```
 function tale(div,w) {
 if(w%20==0) {
    $(div).text(w);
    $(div).css("width",w);
 } else {
    w = Math.floor(w / 20)*20;
    $(div).text(w);
    $(div).css("width",w);
 }
}
$(window).resize(function() {
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    tale(".twenty",windowWidth); 
});

tale(".twenty",$(window).width());
```